# How I can change material, like diffuse, on 3D model (.usdz or .obj)?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am new to swift and AR. I'm trying a project on AR and ran into a problem that I can't change the material on the models. With geometry such as a sphere or a cube, everything is simple.

Tell me what am I doing wrong? My simple code:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
  var modelNode: SCNNode!
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    sceneView.delegate = self
        
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/jacket.usdz")!
        
    modelNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "jacket", recursively: true)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/58.png")

        
    modelNode.childNodes[0].geometry?.materials = [material]
        
    sceneView.scene = scene
```

Comment: Please edit your question. It is unclear what you want to achieve. Provide enough reproducible code and describe your problem.

Comment: Have you tryed to remove the childNode expression in this example? like only: modelNode.geometry?.materials = [material] instead of: modelNode.childNodes[0].geometry?.materials = [material] (you need the exact node to change the material correctly)